# ADFS Password expiration claims not showing on IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, adfs, claims

I have a Relying Party (RP) set up on ADFS, with different claims and when the password is about to expire for a user on AD two more claims appear:

```
type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordexpirationtime => value: 2015-04-23T18:27:14.596Z 
type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordexpirationdays => value: 2
```

but this two claims don't show on IE, while show on Chrome, Firefox, Safari when the user logs in thru ADFS.

Does anyone has a clue on why on IE those claims doesn't show and in others browsers do?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ADFS Management Console and:

1. turn ON Forms Authentication.
2. turn OFF Windows Authentication.

with this IE will redirect the login process to ADFS website base on forms authentication (instead of prompting the windows authentication) and will get the expiration claims.